# ¿Como obtener un dato de un array que está dentro de otro array en python?

Tags: python, array

me gustaria saber si yo tengo un array, por ejemplo:

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

y me gustaria imprimir por pantalla solo el numero 2 ¿Como se haria?

Pd:estoy usando python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se accede como una matriz. En tu caso de acceder al 2 seria

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(array[0][1])
```

En donde el primer cero hace referencia al primer elemento de la lista grande que actua como contenedora de las otras dos y el 1 hace referencia al elemento que se encuentra en la posicion de la lista mas chica... en este caso el elemento es el 2.

Saludos